# What type of origin does Mothra have in Godzilla: King Of The Monsters?

Tags: godzilla-king-of-monsters

Mothra in [*Godzilla: King Of The Monsters* (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3741700/) seems very weak compared to older Godzilla films, with less powers but larger wings. What origins does she have in this film and are they different from earlier backstories?

Answer (score 2):

In almost all back stories, Mothra is shown as an egg which hatches into a larvae.  In King Of The Monsters (hereafter abbreviated **KOTM**), this egg was discovered in a temple and has been monitored by the organization **MONARCH** for several years.  In the original Toho appearance, the egg had simply washed up on the shore in Japan.

In the original Toho appearance, Mothra was a deity.  A mystical, divine being.  In KOTM, Mothra is a prehistoric insect-like species that lived during the same time period as Godzilla.

As far as powers, they're somewhat consistent.  The larvae stage uses silk to incapacitate enemies, while the imago version possesses an abdominal stinger, forelimbs for close combat, wings that generate wind, and also silk.  Being based on a moth, it's also fragile and susceptible to heat, which are some pretty glaring weaknesses.  One major difference is that in her Toho films, she could fire poison darts.  In KOTM, that was replaced by a single abdominal stinger.

Comment: In this 2019 film she had no wings for hurricane or long rage attributes to attack like beams

Comment: I recall in one of the films she had the ability to shoot some type of ray from her antennae, but that definitely wasn't in the KOTM one.  Being that her darts were replaced by a stinger, she seemed to lose all of her long-range attacks.